# MS Project time management scheduling

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, time-management

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to make a project auto-predict time usage for my team but only allow each project to use a certain % of time a day.

Ex. I have Project 1-4 and employee 1-3.

Can I make it do something like...

Project 1 use 50% of employee 1's time every day and then project 2-4 use the rest equally out of an 8 hour day?

I can not seem to find any way in which this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Microsoft Project.

If I'm interpreting properly your question, you want to get several projects using same resource pool.

So, at first, you need to create a resource pool (there's plenty of information how to do it either in the Microsoft Project web, or even in this fórum - I didn't check in deep however - ).

If you want to limit the resource usage for a Project, the only possibility I see is to assign multiple names to a single resource in time-slots (e.g. Resource_1_Slot1, Resource_1_Slot2, etc...). Each time slot can be assigned to a fraction of the resource (e,g 2h, 4h, etc...).
So, if some of the slots is already planned, a conflict (red man) will appear & you can  realise & use different slot.
Drawback is that you need to properly define time slots for a single resource in different names, & utilization efficiency of every resource in total is difficult to monitor. However, for the different projects, is posible to be aware of resources constraints.

Hope it helps.